# Jquery autocomplete with coldfusion

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion, autocomplete

I'm trying to do a simple jquery autocomplete using ColdFusion, [based on Jens great example](http://www.jensbits.com/2010/03/18/jquery-ui-autocomplete-with-coldfusion/).

**HTML:**

```
<form name="merchantSearch" id="merchantSearch" method="post" action="/index.cfm/shop.store/">                  
        <input type="text" name="state" id="state"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="" class="searchButton"/>                          
        <input type="hidden" name="merchantID" id="merchantID"/>
 </form>
```

The entire json struct shows in the select box.  When you click on one, it populates it with the entire struct.  The autocomplete seems really confused about what to do with the json.

**ColdFusion:**

```
    <cfloop query="request.qMerchants">
        <cfset request.merchantStruct = StructNew()>
        <cfset request.merchantStruct["merchantID"] = #request.qMerchants.merchantID#>

        <cfset request.altText = altText..."
        <cfset request.merchantStruct["label"] = #request.qMerchants.merchant#&#request.altText#>

    <cfset ArrayAppend(request.merchantArray, request.merchantStruct)>
</cfloop>


<cfoutput>  
    #serializeJSON(request.merchantArray)#
</cfoutput>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#state").autocomplete(          
           "xhr/merchantAutoComplete.cfm",     
           {
           minLength:2, 
           minchars:2,
           autoFill:false,
           select:function(event,ui) {
               $("#merchantID").val(ui.item.merchantID);
               $("#merchant").val(ui.item.merchant);
             }
           }
      );     

});
```

The CF file returns the json formatted data, but it stays as json.  The results end up like:

```js
[
 {"label":"AAA 112 pts\/$","merchantID":6},
 {"label":"BBB 64 pts\/$","merchantID":62},
 {"label":"CCC  48 pts\/$","merchantID":277},
 {"label":"DDD 144 pts\/$","merchantID":278},
 {"label":"EEE  80 pts\/$","merchantID":279}
]
```

And selecting one puts the whole json struct in the select box.  I assume I have the right group of jquery, jquery UI, and css files to get anything back, but I'll post them just to make this really bloated:

```
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery1.4.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/jquery.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />
<script src="/assets/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

I'm sure its a 'label/value' issue, but nothing seems to help.  Any suggestions would be awesome..Thanks!! Jon

Still haven't figured this out. I think the remote call is returning a properly formatted json struct.  Looks like:
 
**[{"value":"FedEx Office  48 pts per $","id":578},{"value":"Fergie Shoes.com  88 pts per $","id":784}]**

the autocomplete js looks like:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#merchantLabel").autocomplete(          
               "xhr/merchantAutoComplete.cfm",     
              {           
               select:function(event,ui) {
                   $("#merchantID").val(ui.item.id);  
                   return false;
                }
              }
         ); 
    });
```

The html looks like:

```
 <form name="merchantSearch" id="merchantSearch" method="post" action="/index.cfm/shop.store/">                  
        <input type="text" name="merchantLabel" id="merchantLabel"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="" class="searchButton"/>                          
        <input type="hidden" name="merchantID" id="merchantID"/>  
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a really old version of both JQuery and JQuery UI there. I cannot track down JQuery UI 1.8.2 so I could not run your code in a like-for-like environment. If I use the current versions, your code works fine if I simply put the `"xhr/merchantAutoComplete.cfm"` into the options object as the value for a property `source`, ie:

```
$("#state").autocomplete({
    source : "xhr/merchantAutoComplete.cfm",
    minLength:2, 
    // etc
```

I used these JQuery files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Which I just copied from the example on the [JQuery Autocomplete example on their webpage](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

I often find that I'm using obsolete versions of JQUery libraries and following contemporary documentation, often things don't work. Argument-order gets changed between versions, and stuff like that. I dunno if that's your problem, but your code basically works. There's a coupla syntax errors in the CFML you posted, but I presume that's because you didn't post your actual code... the code you posted doesn't even compile, and you'd know about that if it was happening in your environment.

Please always make sure to post *correct* code when you post here. And posting complete and self-contained examples would also help (your example code is incomplete, and has external dependencies on missing code). Some [rhetoric from me and some useful links re how/what to post](http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/short-self-contained-correct-compilable.html) can be found on my blog.

Comment: Oh yeah. Also read up on when you do and when you do NOT have to use pound-signs in CFML: http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/when-to-use-pound-signs.html

Comment: Thanks for looking at this so quickly.  I left a lot out of the cfml page because I felt like the json object was being built correctly and I had already posted so much. I was hoping you had some insight in the jquery file. When I changed to more current jquery files I broke other things on the site so I was hoping I could use the older files. Guess I'll have to bring everything up to date.  I'll give you an update when 'Modernize' things. Thanks again!!

Comment: Hang on, I'm not saying that it *can't* be made to work with the older versions - indeed I'm certain it can be - just that *I* couldn't get all the same resources you were using, so could not really tinker around too much with it. I also hasten to add I am just a journeyman when it comes to JQuery, so I need to actually run code & experiment, I can't just look at things and have experience to know why it won't work, etc. Hopefully someone with more of a clue than I have will also take a look at this! If you can post your JQuery files to somewhere I can grab them from, I'll have more of a look

Comment: See more criteria above.  Still can't get the input box to handle the json struct correctly...

Comment: The issue has been resolved.  I am using an early version of autocomplete that has none of the json callbacks available.  It simply returns a string.  Once I wrapped my head around that, the implemention was simple.